# How can I use 'System.out.printf' to make my code look need

Tags: java

How can I use 'System.out.printf' to make my code look need.
I want my calculations to look like this:

[image: this is how I want my code to look alike]
not like this:

[image: I dont want it to look like this]

I have to use the printf function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Maken van een scanner met de naam input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Welke tafel wilt u printen? ");
    int tafelGetal = input.nextInt();

    int nummer = 0;
    int maxGetal = 10;

    System.out.println("De tafel van " + tafelGetal + ":");

    do {
        int nummer2;
        nummer2 = ++nummer;
        nummer = nummer2;
        int berekening = tafelGetal * nummer;

        if (nummer >= 5) {

            System.out.print("\t" + berekening + "\t");

        }
        if (nummer == 5) {

            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        if (nummer < 5) {

            System.out.print("\t" + berekening + "\t");

        }

    } while (nummer != maxGetal);
    System.out.println(""); 
    
}
```

Comment: Taking a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html could be helpful.

Comment: This is useful : https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Spring16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Comment: %n is a newline in printf

Comment: `System.out.printf("%3d %3d%n%3d %3d%n", 1, 23, 456, 7);`

Comment: Please show the fruits of your efforts and researches in your question.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

reusing some of your var names

```
    int tafelGetal = 3;
    int maxGetal = 10;        
    int numberPerLine = 5;
    int columnWidth = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxGetal; i += numberPerLine) { //iterate over output lines
        for (int j = 0; j < numberPerLine && i + j <= maxGetal; j++) { //iterate over columns
            int berekening = (i + j) * tafelGetal;
            System.out.printf("%" + columnWidth + "d", berekening);//format as number with specified width
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

For further details regarding available formats just go here : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `String.format()` to achieve that:

**Example:**

```
for(int i=3; i<=15; i+=3)
    System.out.print( p(i, 4) );
System.out.println();
for(int i=18; i<=30; i+=3)
    System.out.print( p(i, 4) );

//for padding the string
public static String p(int val, int spaces) {
     return String.format("%1$" + spaces + "s", val);  
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   3   6   9  12  15
  18  21  24  27  30
```

Comment: This solution is terrible.  Just use printf formatting.

Comment: @DwB The solution is only 1 line. The rest are for printing a sample output so OP knows how it works.

Comment: @Stefan Basically, my answer is as simple as `String.format("%1$4s", i)`, where `i` is your value.